# Data Sources in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, datasource, terraform

I had a general question in regards to data sources in terraform. Can you specify a data source in terraform for a particular resource even if that resource is not present in your environment and expect it to retrieve information regarding that resource or when specifying a data source, does it create the resource and then just return the information in the data source block. I hope this makes sense. Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

A Terraform data source allows you to refer to other data, configuration, or infrastructure defined in another Terraform configuration or outside source. Referencing a resource defined in a data source won't create the resource itself, and your plan will fail if you reference nonexistent data or infrastructure.

One example to help understand this is the `aws_ami` datasource: if you reference a nonexistent AWS AMI in an `aws_ami` datasource block, your Terraform plan will fail -- e.g. it won't try to create an AMI, but can only reference an existing one.

[From the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html):

> Data sources allow data to be fetched or computed for use elsewhere in Terraform configuration. Use of data sources allows a Terraform configuration to make use of information defined outside of Terraform, or defined by another separate Terraform configuration.